# Bandwidth setting for ksmooth in R

Tags: r, regression, bandwidth, smoothing

I'm new to R. When I try to use the "ksmooth" function, I'm a little confused with the function description about bandwidth: "The kernels are scaled so that their quartiles (viewed as probability densities) are at +/- 0.25*bandwidth." Can anyone please help explain how this scaling works? If I were to code this kernel smoothing function in Matlab, do I need to put a factor for the bandwidth? Thanks!

Comment: This question seems more suited to be asked at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) since its more related to the theoretical side of the algorithm, rather then software related.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will try Cross Validated later.